# Login .Net Identiy User Using Jwt NodeJs Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-core, webapi

Converting `.Net` api into `Node.js`, now I need to login user using `Identity` table using...

```
var user = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userDto.Username).Result;

var result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, userDto.Password);
```

One option is to use plain query but it does not seem like a feasible solution.
Please kindly let me know what should I do?

Comment: Where is the JWT???

Comment: Please add more information to the question, thanks :)